# OpenSuse installer crashes on Dell XPS13

Tags: system-installation, opensuse

I'm trying to run the installer on my new Dell XPS13. I had an old version of this computer for years and it worked excellent, however, now with the new hardware I see there are a lot of issues.

I run the full installer and it crashes.

So I ran the net installer in save mode, without any kernel modules enabled. Basically when I try to load any module (e.g. wlan) or even list kernel modules it crashes.

Help!

If I can't figure this out by the end of the day I'll have to return the computer and go for the Mac instead. I don't have time for this at work, but have been happily working with OpenSuse for 10 years already. Such a shame... I tried with the latest build as well, same thing...

Comment: Apparently Ubuntu (so I assume Kubuntu as well), run well. I might try to go with Kubuntu then. Hoping this is a minimal change for me.

Comment: Any useful info in the crash(es)? Process crash(es) or kernel crash(es)? Same crash(es) regardless of the install method attempted? Any file or function names in the tracebacks which could narrow the focus a bit?

Comment: Not opensuse-specific, but maybe providing some hints - a pretty detailed and recent linux on xps13 discussion: https://major.io/2015/02/03/linux-support-dell-xps-13-9343-2015-model/